# Set dynamically width and height in menuItem xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu

I'm new in XAML and WPF, and now I seems to be having big problem. I separate my grid in parts with `Grid.RowDefinition` and `Grid.ColumnDefinition` and I set one of my menus to have `Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"` And when there is a change in the size of the window the menu size is changed, but menuItems size is not changed. I can't explain very good, and for that I show you two pictures
first is in not in full screen, and second is in the full screen

[image]

[image]

My question is: How can display to look good in every size of screen (in full screen and in not full screen) Here is and part of my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3.6*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3.6*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="13*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="65*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="#e6ebeb" BorderBrush="#dce3e2" BorderThickness="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Menu Name="HeadMenu" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent">
                <Menu.DataContext>
                    <vms:HeadMenuViewModel />
                </Menu.DataContext>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Settings}" Background="#fff" Foreground="#4d5d61" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="0 1 0 0">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="Settings" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Help}" Background="#fff" Foreground="#4d5d61" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Margin="0 1 0 0">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="Help" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You need `MenuItem` follow Windows Size? For example, When window small, 2 button small, When window full screen, 2 button big?

Comment: @ebattulga can I do that only with xaml? Or I need to write and in my case c# code. I need this menuItems to be part of part of Grid.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you want like this, code is here

```
<Menu Height="20">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Height="20" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" Header="Settings" Grid.Column="0"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Height="20" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" Header="Help" Grid.Column="1"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to accomplish by `ScaleTransform`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.2" ScaleY="1.2" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
  text
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Is working. I don't understand really how but is working. But not really good. Where exactly need to put this code for working correct. Now i try to put inside in menu and change text to be menuItem.

Comment: @evelikov92 do you want to resize `FontSize` proportinally or `MenyItems ` to be resized when Windows size is changed?

Comment: Yeah. I need to be responsive. For user is not care what part of monitor screen is used (is full screen or is not).

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Grid for Menu as Best Practice. Use DockPanel.
2. You want Menu to always get the height it actually needs always. So, set Height of 2nd RowDefinition to Auto.

   ```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="13*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="65*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   ```

Comment: For now this with Height="Auto" is best solution. In my case also I think almost everything is need to be auto. Is working thanks